# Multiple where queries to select date range and top 5 highest value for a variable

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

## Background

I am creating an app where users can submit a post at any time. One of the main feature of the app is that users in a group can start a session to vote for the best posts, within a period of time (e.g. all post from the last 10 days).

The app then presents the posts in a table view. Users can change the type of posts displayed using a segmented control. Once all users have voted, then the next view controller will display the result of the vote - showing only the top 5 posts for each category ("well", "notWell", "confused")

This is how I have structured it in Firebase Database.

- Each user must belong to a group - e.g. "Balance Banana".
- Every post must belong to one of three category - e.g. "well", "notWell", "confused".
- Each post must have a date.

[image]

## Question

How should I develop the feature to "display top 5 posts for each category"?

I need to retrieve 5 post with the highest vote count for each post type where date is > x.

I have looked at the several questions on SO relating to querying multiple where clauses with Firebase Database and I think the most suitable approach is to use the QueryOrderedBy to filter the date, then code the logic to extract the top 5 posts within each category. If this is a suitable approach, how should I go about iterating through each snapshot.children and create a dictionary of top 5 posts for each category?

### SO Posts related to multiple where clause in Firebase Database.

[Query based on multiple where clauses in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase) has an excellent answer by Frank van Puffelen relating to this topic.

## Current code

```
func loadData() {

    self.ref.child("session").child((self.currentUser?.team)!).queryOrdered(byChild: "date").queryStarting(atValue: postStartDate).observe(.value, with: {
        snapshot in

        var wellItems: [SessionPost] = []
        var notWellItems: [SessionPost] = []
        var confusedItems: [SessionPost] = []

        for item in snapshot.children {
            let postItem = SessionPost(snapshot: item as! DataSnapshot)
            if let postType = postItem.type {
                switch postType {
                case "well":
                    wellItems.append(postItem)
                case "notWell":
                    notWellItems.append(postItem)
                case "confused":
                    confusedItems.append(postItem)
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        self.topWellPostItems = wellItems
        self.topNotWellPostItems = notWellItems
        self.topConfusedPostItems = confusedItems
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

For each of your `SessionPost` arrays you would have to sort based on `voteCount`. Such as

```
wellItems.sort(by: { $0.voteCount > $1.voteCount })
topFiveItems = Array(wellItems.sort[0 ..< 5])
```

Comment: Thanks @jože-ws. Firstly, SessionPost is a dictionary. I managed to sort the items based on voteCount using wellItems.sorted(by: { $0.voteCount! > $1.voteCount!} ). But how do I limit the maximum number of items in topWellPostItems to only 3?

Comment: @Jason100. Great. If this answer the question, mark it as an answer then

Comment: I still haven't been able to limit the number of items in the dictionary. Any advice?

Comment: For that you will need to slice the array and get the first five items. Check out the edits

Comment: Unfortunately it's a dictionary. How should I go about slicing a dictionary?

Comment: how can topWellPostItems be a dictionary and wellItems be an array. You are assigning one to the other

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158748/discussion-between-jason100-and-joze-ws).